# Why when applying a float:right; in this specific case does it cause the div to go under the previous div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a div float to the right however when applying float:right and making the page size smaller with the browser the div goes under the previous div.

https://jsfiddle.net/Crystalwolf/bku2f08c/1/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="navbar-container">
    <div id="mainlogo">
    </div>
    <div id="sublogo">
      This is a subtitle test
    </div>
    <div id="navbutton-container">
      <div class="navbutton navcurrent">
        Home
      </div>
      <div class="navbutton">
        About
      </div>
      <div class="navbutton">
        Web Design
      </div>
      <div class="navbutton">
        Programming
      </div>
      <div class="navbutton">
        Graphic Design
      </div>
      <div class="navbutton">
        Contact
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carousel">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#navbar-container {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 60px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  min-width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#mainlogo {
  color: #373c40;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left:50px;
}

#sublogo {
  color: #373c40;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#carousel {
  background-image: url("http://3nacu.com/unique/images/stars.png");
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#navbutton-container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  float: right;                  //THIS SPECIFIC FLOAT RIGHT
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right:50px;
}

.navbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #373c40;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbutton:hover {
  background-color: #373c40;
  color: white;
}

.navcurrent {
  background-color: #B39EB5;
  color: white;
}
```

e.g Have the browser at 1920 on the result and it's all on one line. As soon as you make it a considerable amount shorter it proceeds to just go under the previous div instead of just enabling a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Which element are we talking about, that should have `float: right`?

Comment: The one I put a comment next too in the code on Stack Overflow

Comment: But having a horizontal scrollbar like that will make your webpage really non user friendly ... do you really want that?

Comment: It's something I want so if they are viewing the website at 1024x768 resolution or lower then it will require a horizontal scroll as to keep the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior, floated elements will break if there's not enough room for them inside the container. If you want a scrollable overflow instead, you need to give the container a fixed width (e.g. `1200px` instead of `100%`) large enough to fit all the floated elements.

Comment: So in the case, without some JS or browser size detection I will be unable to fix this without having a fixed container size?

Comment: You could remove the floats and instead use `display: table-cell` on the elements and `display: table` on their container. That way the elements will never wrap.

You can then add `overflow: auto` to show a scrollbar as soon as the viewport is too narrow to accomodate the content.

Comment: Doing it via tables however then causes the issue of what I want floating to the right now becoming static.

Comment: You could give the container element a width of 100%, set the text-align of the outermost right table-cell to right and make the contained element inline-block. That way it will always stick to the container's right side.